# Is it a good practice to have 2 winforms in the same application one for dashboard and one for output?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it a good practice to have two forms in the same application in c# and opening both at the same time ?

I have one form for LOG's output and one as a dashboard for configuration etc. ?

Comment: That's a normal design, I even had many more 2 forms.

Comment: You should also ask this on http://ux.stackexchange.com/, since this is more of a user experience question that a technical one in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can.

But for the common case of the "log output", I personally often use a `SplitContainer` control with 2 panels (one for the log, the other for everything else), in a single form.

Comment: How do you append output to the log output? I guess there is a limitation of the amount of chars it can store on the same time.

Comment: @0x90 Well it depends. How does your "log" control looks like? You can choose any control to append log (listview, textbox...) in a panel.